# Python List: Weird Behavior When Disaggregating Dictionary Field

Tags: python, list

I have data stored in the following format:

```
name    address    id
person   place     A123
person2  place2    A345
person3  place3    A445;A456
person4  place4    A333
```

I want to convert it to:

```
name    address    id
person   place     A123
person2  place2    A345
person3  place3    A445
person3  place3    A456
person4  place4    A333
```

I'm trying to do it with this:

```
    combined_file_array = []
    for index, row in enumerate(data):
        if (';' not in row['id']):
            combined_file_array.append(row)
        else:
            ids = row['id'].split(';')
            for id in ids:
                combined_file_array.append(row)
                combined_file_array[-1]['id'] = id.strip()
```

This code produces the equivalent of:

```
name    address    id
person   place     A123
person2  place2    A345
person3  place3    A456
person3  place3    A456
person4  place4    A333
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: You appended *the same dictionary* to your list twice.  Setting the `'id'` entry via one of those references is equally visible via the other reference.  Try `.append(row.copy())` so that the repeated dicts are independently modifiable.

Comment: Thanks Jason - that solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mutating the same dictionary, so you end up changing the id for both of your rows.

By doing

```
combined_file_array[-1]['id'] = id.strip()
```

you're not only changing `combined_file_array[-1]['id']` but also `combined_file_array[-2]['id']` because they both point towards the same dict.

Answer (score 0):

By appending the same dict `row` in each iteration over `ids` and updating the `id` key to the same dict, you overwrite the value of the `id` key in the previous iterations.

You should append a new copy of the dict from `row` instead. Since you are going to update the `id` key, you can `pop` it first, and then use generic unpacking to update its value:

```
for id in row.pop('id').split(';'):
    combined_file_array.append({**row, 'id': id})
```